# Consulta en PHP de una base de datos en Oracle Express 21c

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle-21c

Tengo problemas con mostrar los datos de mi base de datos en mi pagina `php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>mostrar datos</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>

    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td>Folio</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Edad</td>
            <td>Sexo</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>Compania</td>   
            <td>Monto</td>  
        </tr>

        <?php 
        $conexion=oci_connect('SYSTEM', 'admin') or die(oci_error());
        if (!$conexion) {
            echo "Error";
        }else{
            $sql="select *from datos";
            echo "Conexion Exitosa";
            $result=oci_parse($conexion,$sql);
            
            oci_execute($result);
            while(($mostrar=oci_fetch_array($result,OCI_ASSOC))!=false){
            
            echo ("
            <tr>
                <td> .$mostrar['Nombre'].</td>");
            //echo $result['Nombre']."<br>\n";
            
        }
    }
        oci_close($conexion);
                
            /*<td>< $mostrar['Edad'] </td>
            <td>< $mostrar['Sexo'] </td>
            <td>< $mostrar['Fecha'] </td>
            <td>< $mostrar['Compania'] </td>
            <td>< $mostrar['Monto'] </td>
                
        </tr>
        ";*/
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html
```

Llevo mucho tiempo con este problema agradecería mucho su ayuda.

La conexión la hace bien, el problema esta al recopilar los datos de la BD o mostrarlos en la pagina, me aparece un problema en el `echo` diciendo que espera "" o "-".

Estoy usando `wamp server` como mediador, pero soy nuevo en cuanto a `Oracle` y me vendría bien un poco de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en esta parte tienes un error, el asterisco debe estar separado del from

```
$sql="select *from datos"
```

Tal que así

```
$sql="select * from datos"
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es Oracle, si no de sintaxis y pasa por que PHP no está entendiendo el contexto del otro substring `['Nombre']` que tienes dentro del string principal, en el `echo`.
Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
php > $a = ['uno'=>1, 'dos'=>2]; // <-- Un array de prueba
php > echo "<td>$a['uno']</td>";
syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" // <-- El error

php > // Pueden haber múltiples soluciones:

php > echo "<td>$a[uno]</td>"; // Quitando las comillas internas
<td>1</td>

php > echo '<td>'.$a['uno'].'</td>'; // Concatenando
<td>1</td>

php > echo "<td>{$a['uno']}</td>"; // Con llaves
<td>1</td>
```