# Contenido variable no imprime en option dentro de select dentro en foreach pero si en value

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con la representación de variables dentro de un foreach en un select:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" name="cursos[]" id="listaCursos"> 
                                
     <?php foreach($cursos as $curso){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $curso['id'];?>" > <?php echo $curso['id'];?> - <?php echo $curso['nombre_curso'];?>  </option>
     <?php } ?>
                                
 </select>
```

El primer echo `$curso['id'];` (el que está dentro del value" se imprime correctamente (aunque no deberia imprimirse ya que es un value. Sin embargo lo que propiamente viene dentro del option: `<?php echo $curso['id'];?> - <?php echo $curso['nombre_curso'];?>` no se imprime.

Es decir, solo se está imprimiendo lo que hay en el value de modo que si meto  `<?php echo $curso['nombre_curso'];?>` esto si se imprime.
Estoy desconcertado porque lo que va dentro del value no se muestra en el select sino lo que va propiamente dentro del option. Como el el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo(no se muestra">Volvo(se muestra)</option>
</select>
```

Pienso que las aperturas y cierres tanto de value como option y <?php esta bien pero tal vez esté equivocado.
¿Alguien sabe sino a qué podría deberse?

Comment: El problema es que PHP no está entendiendo el contexto de las comillas internas. La solución rápida es eliminar las comillas internas. Mira los ejemplos que pongo en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/582723/80870)

Comment: @aeportugal Creo que en este caso el problema reside en un script llamado TomSelect el cual estaba reemplazando el "option" por un "div" para darle estilos al select. De ahí que no imprimiera correctamente. Una vez quitado el script funciona perfectamente. Por un momento pensé que nada tenía sentido. Gracias de todas formas!

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de dar con el porque de esta situación. Un script llamado TomSelect estaba cambiando el option por div cambiando totalmente el contexto y al parecer esto evitaba la correcta impresion dentro del option. Una vez anulado el script funciona correctamente. Me gustaría borrar esta pregunta para que nadie pierda el tiempo con ella.